# Fuzzyjoin regex being very slow & running out of memory

Tags: r, optimization, fuzzyjoin

I want to join two dfs with `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(df1,df2, by=c(name="name")` where `df1` has 45k rows,  and `df2` has 2.5mil. This results in a memory error. If I split `df1` up into chunks of 1000 rows, each chunk takes 15 minutes to run.

It turned out faster (but still slow) to have a for loop iterating through `df1` rows, do the regex using the %ilike% operator from `data.table` and parallelize this loop.

Is this the best I can get? Any way of speeding up the fuzzyjoin for large tables like this?

EDIT:

example data:

```
df1 <- tibble("name"=c("^(?i)SMITH( r.|-| [ivx]| .*)$","^(?i)BLACK( r.|-| [ivx]| .*)$","^(?i)MILLER( r.|-| [ivx]| .*)$"),
              "fname1"=c("JOHN","THOMAS","JAMES"),
              "id1"=c("aaaa","bbbb","cccc"))

df2 <- tibble("name"=c("Smith Jr.","Black III","Miller-Muller","Smith","Smith"),
              "fname2"=c("Jon","Tom","Jamie","John","Johnathan"),
              "id2"=c("1111","2222","3333","4444","5555"))
```

Comment: Perhaps. Can you give us a structure/minimal example of what df1 and df2 look like?

Comment: It may be faster to perform this in 2 parts.  Do a `left_join()` then a fuzzy_join for the unmatched.  If you do a simple `left_join()` how many matches do you get?

Comment: added example data.

Comment: @Dave2e I don't get anything since the name column (that I'm joining by) is formatted differently in the two dfs, hence the need for regex