# Parallelizing code for matching between two data frames

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelize a function that works roughly like this:

```
process_row <- function(i, db1, db2){
    row <- db1[,i]
    match_db <- db2 %>% dplyr::filter(name_clear == row$name)
    out <- cbind(row, match_db)
}

out_list <- lapply(1:length(db1), process_row, db1=db1, db2=db2)
```

In reality it's more complicated but the basic idea is that it goes row-by-row through `db1`, finds appropriate matching rows in `db2` according to a set of rules, and then binds them together column-wise (one-to-many relationship). In terms of size, `db1` has 40k rows, `db2` has 6 million. The matches (`out`) are usually between 1 and 100 rows long.

When I run the regular lapply, it takes up very little CPU & memory. I can "manually" paralellize it by opening up multiple instances of Rstudio and changing the range of the `lapply` to `1:10000` in the first one, `10001:20000` in the second, etc. but that's ridiculous. Unfortunately it's the only "working" solution I found so far. Neither `foreach` nor `future.apply` work - they just crash after running out of memory completely, even on a range of `1:10`.

I suspect this has to do with the way I wrote the function. How should I change it?

Comment: This sounds like a `dplyr::left_join(db1, db2, by = c(name = "name_clear")` or similar; it would help if you presented a simple reproducible example...

Comment: @MartinMorgan the process is  more complicated, the matching is done on regexes so won't work with regular joins

Comment: Please add a simple reproducible example (e.g., db1 with 2 rows, db2 with 3 rows?), including desired output; the role of regular expressions is not at all obvious in your question, and as written you iterate over columns, not rows...

Comment: Maybe the fuzzyjoin package???

Comment: @Dave2e doesn't work with big tables, "failed to allocate a vector of size 600GB" - lol

Answer (score 0):

Here's a familiar dataset for `db1`

```
library(dplyr)
db1 = as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = "model")
```

From your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70999051/fuzzyjoin-regex-being-very-slow-running-out-of-memory), I'm guessing that you might have something analogous to a tibble
of 'brands' and a corresponding regular expression to extract brands
that have models associated with them.

```
db2 <-
    db1 |>
    mutate(
        brand = sub(" .*", "", model),
        brand_re = paste0("^(?i)", brand, "( .*)$")
    ) |>
    select(brand, brand_re) |>
    distinct()
```

and you'd like to do the equivalent of

```
fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(db1, db2, by = c(model = "brand_re")) |>
    ## just a few columns to illustrate
    select(brand, model, mpg, cyl, disp, drat, wt)
```

The problem with using fuzzyjoin for your case is that it tries to be
efficient by making two parallel vectors that capture all combinations
of unique regular expressions and unique values to pass to the
`stringi::stri_detect()` function, but of course with 45k regular
expressions and 6 million values, those are very long vectors!

The challenge with your approach to parallelization is that too much data
is used in the `lapply()`, and the operations (repeatedly subsetting a
very large data.frame and binding columns) are not efficient.

Instead, write a function that performs the necessary computation with
only the necessary data. Here we iterate over the patterns of
interest, and return a list of integer vectors indexing the `str`
(`model` in our case) matching the corresponding regular expression.

```
fuzzy_match <- function(str, patterns) {
    lapply(patterns, function(pattern, str) {
        which(stringi::stri_detect_regex(str, pattern))
    }, str)
}
joins <- fuzzy_match(db1$model, db2$brand_re)
str(head(joins))
```

For instance, the first element of `joins` says that the first regular
expression of `db2$brand_re` matches elements 1 and 2 of `db1$model`.

We can then construct the joint table by constructing relevant indexes
and binding rows

```
db1_idx <- unlist(joins)
db2_idx <- rep(seq_along(joins), lengths(joins))
## FIXME: not quite a join, since regular expressions in db2 with no
## matches in db1 are not present
cbind(db2[db2_idx,], db1[db1_idx,]) |>
    as_tibble() |>
    select(brand, model, mpg, cyl, disp, drat, wt)
```

When `str` is of length 5 million, this seems to take about 1 second
per regular expression, so 45k regular expressions is still a long time. The first step is to
ask whether there are improvements to the naive implementation of
`fuzzy_match()` that would speed it up. For instance if the `str`
contains duplicates, it might be beneficial to only do the match on
unique values.

```
fuzzy_match_with_duplicates <- function(str, patterns) {
    ## only iterate on unique values; useful if many duplicates
    ustr <- unique(str)
    uresult <- lapply(patterns, function(pattern, str) {
        which(stringi::stri_detect_regex(str, pattern))
    }, ustr)
    ## unpack ustr
    lapply(uresult, function(i) which(str %in% ustr[i]))
}
```

It might also pay to study the regular expressions and eliminate
redundancies, for instance in the present case we could obtain relevant
results (expect for models without brands) with single pass

```
db1 |>
    mutate(brand = sub(" .*", "", model))
```

In the example of your previous post it seems like one could make progress by replacing specific patterns with `SMITH` etc. with `[[:alpha:]]+` or similar.

If the function is still slow, the goal is now to parallelize a simple
`lapply()` with modest data. On Linux or macOS the easiest solution is
to use `parallel::mclapply()`

```
## save some cores for other things...
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores() - 2L)
fuzzy_match_parallel_mclapply <- function(str, patterns) {
    mcapply(patterns, function(pattern, str) {
        which(stringi::stri_detect_regex(str, pattern))
    }, str)
}
```

On Windows the easiest approach is to use `parallel::parLapply()` with
a socket-based back end

```
fuzzy_match_parallel_sockets <- function(str, patterns) {
    parLapply(cl, patterns, function(pattern, str) {
        which(stringi::stri_detect_regex(str, pattern))
    }, str)
}

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores() - 2L)
joins <- fuzzy_match_parallel_sockets(db1$model, db2$brand_re)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Subsequent processing steps are unchanged.